# Some problems regarding invariant subspaces and kernels

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$T: V \to V$ is a linear operator

Let $V_\lambda (T) = \{v \in V : T(v) = \lambda v\}$. Prove $V_\lambda (T)$ is an invariant subspace of $V$.

For this, I am stuck. I think I need to show first that $V_\lambda (T)$ is a subspace of $V$. Which it is because $T$ is a linear operator and is closed under scalar multiplication. So then by definition of invariant subspace, for every $v\in V$, I need to show that $V_\lambda (v) \in V$. But I don't know if this is true because $\lambda v$ may or may not be in $V$.

Secondly I need to show $Ker(T) = V_0(T)$.

$Ker(T) =\{ v \in V : T(v) = 0\}$ and $V_0(T) = \{ v \in V: T(v)= 0 v = 0\} = \{ v \in V : T(v) = 0\} $. I don't think this is right.

Thirdly I need to show that $V_\lambda (T) =Ker(T - \lambda I)$.

$V_\lambda (T) = \{v \in V : T(v) = \lambda v\}$ but what is $Ker(T-\lambda I)$? Is it $\{ v \in V : T(v) - \lambda I  = 0\}$? The Kernel here is stopping me from finishing.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\ker (T - \lambda I) = \{ v \in V : T(v) - \lambda v  = 0\}.$

Comment: $\lambda v \in V$ by definition of a vector space.

Comment: @AOrtiz that is kind of confusing as to why that is. The notation is I mean. I understand what you wrote. But just for my knowledge, why wouldn't it be written as $ker(T−λvI)=\{v∈V:T(v)−λv=0\}$?

Comment: $T - \lambda I$ is itself a map from $V\to V$. If $v \in \ker(T-\lambda I)$, then $(T-\lambda I)v = T(v) - \lambda I(v)= T(v) - \lambda v = 0$. Ask yourself what $\lambda v I$ is. It is not a map $V\to V$, that's for sure. It doesn't even make sense as it is written.

Comment: Ok. When you explained it like that, that made sense. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

Saying that $V_\lambda(T)$ is an invariant subspace of $V$ means
$$\hbox{if $\bf v$ is in $V_\lambda(T)$ then $T({\bf v})$ is in $V_\lambda(T)$}.$$
That is,
$$\hbox{if $T({\bf v})=\lambda{\bf v}$ then $T(T({\bf v}))=\lambda T({\bf v})$}.$$
This follows immediately from the fact that $T(\lambda{\bf u})=\lambda T({\bf u})$ for all $\bf u$ and all $\lambda$.

That's all you have to do, it is nowhere near as complicated as you seem to think.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm sort of half getting what you mean. So I agree with everything up until the end but how is it that $\lambda T(u) \in V$? $\lambda$ is a scalar. That last part is confusing me.

Comment: @Nid $T( \mathbf{u})$ is a vector in $V$ and $\lambda$ is a scalar, and vector spaces are closed under scalar multiplication

Comment: Oh ok. I misinterpreted what "closed under" means in abstract algebra in relation to vector spaces. Thank you.